# Is there a way to stop facebook Fresco from loading large images

Tags: android, fresco

I have some crash reports related to OutOfMemoryError during playing animated gifs.

com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.impl.AnimatedDrawableCachingBackendImpl.createNewBitmap java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

We don't have a control over some of the animated gifs size.

Our stack trace is the same with:
https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1259

Fresco documentation clearly states that the only jpeg resize is supported.
**Is there any way to work around it?**
Probably restrict image size to load.
I'll prefer to don't display the image rather than crash in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's possible to set your own custom ImageDecoder.
I wrapped default decoder with my implementation which verifies the image size and throws an exception in case it's too big.